# Prevent default formatting (comma insertion) of long argument in s:message tag

Tags: java, spring, resourcebundle

I have a jsp in which I use spring s:message tag

```
<s:message code="application.success" arguments="${applicationRefId}" />
```

applicationRefId is a long variable added to the model.

In my resource bundle, I have defined message code quite regularly as

```
application.success=Application {0} successfully submitted
```

But this results in

```
Application 74,311 successfully submitted
```

Here my long value is formatted with commas. I have two questions - Why does this formatting happen, by default, and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know you can either

1. convert `applicationRefId` to String before passing it to messageTag
2. or apply formatting in your resource bundle

   ```
    application.success=Application {0, number, #} successfully submitted
   ```

**Second solution documentation**

- [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)
- [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

From the `MessageFormat` documentation

> ```
> FormatElement:
>      { ArgumentIndex }
>      { ArgumentIndex , FormatType }
>      { ArgumentIndex , FormatType , FormatStyle }
> ```

And this chart
[image]

Comment: thanks, the second solution worked perfectly. Do you know of any api reference for custom formatting in resource bundle.